# How to find the mouse hover positions (preferably timestamps) on a video?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, video-capture

I am trying to save the mouse hover positions in a given video. I need to load the video on a 'Load Video' button press. When the mouse is outside the canvas no (x,y) should be saved. I also want the video to streamed at much lower rate (say, 4 times slower). Presently, I have the following code:`

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import PIL.Image,PIL.ImageTk 
import time
import cv2


class App:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_source=0):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
        self.video_source = video_source
        self.video_loaded=False

    # open video source (by default this will try to open the computer webcam)
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source)

    # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = self.vid.width, height = 
        self.vid.height)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.bind('<Motion>',self.canvas.motion)
       #self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
       #self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

       # Button that lets the user take a snapshot
        self.btn_snapshot=tk.Button(window, text="Snapshot", width=50,  
        command=self.snapshot)
        self.btn_snapshot.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)

        self.btn_collapse=tk.Button(window, text="Collapse", width=50, 
        command=self.collapse)
        self.btn_collapse.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)

        self.btn_load_video=tk.Button(window, text="Load Video", width=50, 
        command=self.load_video)
        self.btn_load_video.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True)

   #if self.video_loaded==True:
     # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically 
     called every delay milliseconds
     self.delay = 15
     self.update()


     self.window.mainloop()

     def load_video(self):
    # open video source (by default this will try to open the computer 
     webcam)
        self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source)
        self.video_loaded=True

     def snapshot(self):
     # Get a frame from the video source
        ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()

     if ret:
        cv2.imwrite("frame-" + time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S") +  ".jpg", 
        cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))

     def collapse(self):
         self.window.quit()  

     def motion(self):
         self.x=self.canvas.winfo_pointerx
         self.y=self.canvas.winfo_pointery
         print('{},{}'.format(self.x, self.y))
         #self.canvas.itemconfigure(text='({x},{y})'.format(x = self.x, 
         y=self.y))
         #print('{},{}'.format(self.x, self.y))      
     #def motion(self):
     #    x, y = self.x, self.y
     #   print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))  

     #def on_enter(self, event):
     #    self.l2.configure(text="Hello world")

     #def on_leave(self, enter):
     #    self.l2.configure(text="")       

     def update(self):
     # Get a frame from the video source
         ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()

     if ret:
        self.photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = 
         PIL.Image.fromarray(frame))
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.photo, anchor = tk.NW)

        self.window.after(self.delay, self.update)

class MyVideoCapture:
    def __init__(self, video_source=0):
    # Open the video source
        video_source='./videofilename.wmv'
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
        if not self.vid.isOpened():
           raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)

    # Get video source width and height
       self.width = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
       self.height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

    def get_frame(self):
        if self.vid.isOpened():
           ret, frame = self.vid.read()
           if ret:
            # Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted 
            to BGR
              return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
           else:
              return (ret, None)
        else:
           return (ret, None)

    # Release the video source when the object is destroyed
    def __del__(self):
       if self.vid.isOpened():
       self.vid.release()

    # Create a window and pass it to the Application object
    root = tk.Tk()           
App(root, "Tkinter and OpenCV")
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/anaconda2/envs/my_env/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 
1541, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: motion() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I want the function motion() to return the mouse hover positions. Appreciate help. Thanks in advance.

Here is [the link](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/04/21/python-opencv-show-video-tkinter-window/) from which the I got the main code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bind()` function sends an event object to the callback function, but the `motion()` function only accepts `self`. Try:

```
def motion(self, event):
    self.x=event.x
    self.y=event.y
```

Binding the function for saving mouse positions can be done as in teh example below.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200+800+50')

c = Canvas(root, bg='tan')
c.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

def motion(event):
    if follow:
        print(event.x, event.y)

follow = False
def follow_motion(event):
    global follow
    follow = not follow

c.bind('<Motion>', motion)
c.bind('<Button-1>', follow_motion)

root.mainloop()
```

Click the left mouse button on the canvas and the function `motion()` is enabled. One more click disables it.

Comment: Thank you. How to I associate a mouse click event to start and stop recording the mouse positions using move() ?

Comment: Also, is there a way to play the video on the canvas window at a much lower frame rate than the original?

Comment: Well, how do you want it to work? You can create a button for starting and stopping or bind it to a keyboard key. I don't know anything about displaying video :(

Comment: Hi. Th code displays the video now, but it instantly starts streaming at the original frame rate.  I intend to load the video via a button click, start playing the video on another button click, that too at a much lower frame-rate(~1/4th).  Start/Stop recording mouse positions on mouse click.

Comment: In my experiment, the object is not present throughout the video. I need to save mouse positions only during the times the object is present in the video. Hence a mouse click on the video for starting and stopping the mouse position recording is an optimal solution, I suppose.

Comment: Updated my answer. Seems usable?

Comment: Thanks. It worked like charm. As of now, the video loads on program run and immediately starts playing at original frame-rate. Can you please tell how to customize the video loading, and have a adjustable frame-rate?

Comment: Or, can I have a video player (such a VLC player) embedded in the Tkinter window so that the video playback is customizable?

Comment: I have not tried to present video in tkinter so I know nothing about that.  Try asking a new question about VLC or displaying video.